# ошибка при использовании Browser-Sync + Gulp

Tags: windows, gulp, browsersync

При попытке добавить в gulpfile: `browserSync = require('browser-sync').create()`

и запуске любой задачи вылетает ошибка.
если закомитить `browserSync = require('browser-sync').create()` - все работает.

**Как исправить?**

ошибка

```
 C:\Users\userName\.node_modules_global\browser-sync:2
    basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
              ^^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
        at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
        at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
        at Module._compile (module.js:607:28)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
        at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\userName\projects\projectName\gulpfile.js:11:19)
```

gulp-файл:

```
 "use strict";

    const gulp = require("gulp"),
        postcss = require('gulp-postcss'),
        sass = require("gulp-sass"),
        concat = require("gulp-concat"),
        debug = require("gulp-debug"),
        sourcemaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps"),
        del = require("del"),
        newer = require("gulp-newer"),
        browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

    gulp.task("hello", function() {
        console.log('HELLO');
    });

    gulp.task("clean", function () {
        return del("production/**")
    });
```

Используется:

Windows-7

gulp Local version 4.0.0-alpha.3 (CLI version 2.0.1)

browser-sync 2.23.6

Comment: Без .create() работает, browser({server: {baseDir: "app"},notify: false});

Comment: не работает.даже если добавить: const browserSync = require('browser-sync'); и на создавать задачи с использованием browserSync - ошибка

Answer (score -1):

Все работает...

При установке Browser-Sync не поставил флаг --save-dev

с флагом все работает